# NextJS - re-using a function from index in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Apologies for the amount of text here, not sure what code is relevant to my problem.
Trying to use an onClick function inside of a component, where the function and dependencies are declared inside of index.js

Function 1: I have a function in my next-app index.js to load data from API, based on user input...
(user enters a player name, press button, displays statistics for that player).

Function 2: I also have another component/function that shows all players from a team/squad using another API endpoint. (select, choose team, press button, displays all players from that team).

I want it so clicking a player name after using function 2, does the same as function 1.

`index.js`:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);
  const [squads, setSquads] = useState([]);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState("Player Name");
  const [squad, setSquad] = useState("default");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setSquad(e.target.value);
  }

  const loadPeople = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const req = await fetch(`/api/player/${player}`);
    const json = await req.json();
    setTeams(json);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const loadSquad = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const req = await fetch(`/api/squad/${squad}`);
    const json = await req.json();
    setSquads(json);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      <Head>
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
          <select value={squad} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option id='example'> Lots of options here, removed to save space 
            </option>
          </select>
          <button onClick={() => loadSquad()}>Load</button>

          <input
            value={player}
            id="player"
            onChange={(e) => setPlayer(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button onClick={() => loadPeople()} id="pbtn">
            Load
          </button>
          {loading && <div className={styles.load}>LOADING</div>}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.teams}>
          <Teams teams={teams} />
          <Squads squadz={squads} />
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Squads component`

```
import React from "react";
const Squads = ({ squadz }) => {
  if (!squadz.teamStats) {
    return null;
  }
  let member = squadz.playerStats;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <br />
      <img src={squadz.teamStats.logo} />
      <br />
      {squadz.teamStats.name}
      <br />
      {squadz.teamStats.wl}
      <br />
      <p />
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-child magenta">
          <button onclick='loadPeople(member[0][0].player)'>{member[0][0].player}</button> 

// ^^^^ this onclick is what i need to work, obviously it doesn't as the function isn't defined here

          <p />
          {member[0][0].role} <p />
          Win Rate: {member[0][0].win_rate}
          <p />
          {member[0][0].matches} <p />
          Total Battles: {member[0][0].total_battles} <p />
          {member[0][0].score} <p />
        </div>

        <div class="flex-child magenta">
          <button class="name">{member[1][0].player}</button>
          <p />
          {member[1][0].role} <p />
          Win Rate: {member[1][0].win_rate}
          <p />
          {member[1][0].matches} <p />
          Total Battles: {member[1][0].total_battles} <p />
          {member[1][0].score} <p />
        </div>

        <div class="flex-child magenta">
          <button class="name">{member[2][0].player}</button>
          <p />
          {member[2][0].role} <p />
          Win Rate: {member[2][0].win_rate}
          <p />
          {member[2][0].matches} <p />
          Total Battles: {member[2][0].total_battles} <p />
          {member[2][0].score} <p />
        </div>

        <div class="flex-child magenta">
          <button class="name">{member[3][0].player}</button>
          <p />
          {member[3][0].role} <p />
          Win Rate: {member[3][0].win_rate}
          <p />
          {member[3][0].matches} <p />
          Total Battles: {member[3][0].total_battles} <p />
          {member[3][0].score} <p />
        </div>
        <div class="flex-child magenta">
          <button class="name">{member[4][0].player}</button>
          <p />
          {member[4][0].role} <p />
          Win Rate: {member[4][0].win_rate}
          <p />
          {member[4][0].matches} <p />
          Total Battles: {member[4][0].total_battles} <p />
          {member[4][0].score} <p />
        </div>
        <div class="flex-child magenta">
          <button class="name">{member[5][0].player}</button>
          <p />
          {member[5][0].role} <p />
          Win Rate: {member[5][0].win_rate}
          <p />
          {member[5][0].matches} <p />
          Total Battles: {member[5][0].total_battles} <p />
          {member[5][0].score} <p />
        </div>
        <div class="flex-child magenta">
          <button class="name">{member[6][0].player}</button>
          <p />
          {member[6][0].role} <p />
          Win Rate: {member[6][0].win_rate}
          <p />
          {member[6][0].matches} <p />
          Total Battles: {member[6][0].total_battles} <p />
          {member[6][0].score} <p />
        </div>
        <div class="flex-child magenta">
          <button class="name">{member[7][0].player}</button>
          <p />
          {member[7][0].role} <p />
          Win Rate: {member[7][0].win_rate}
          <p />
          {member[7][0].matches} <p />
          Total Battles: {member[7][0].total_battles} <p />
          {member[7][0].score} <p />
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Squads;
```

`Teams component (not sure if relevant to this problem but here it is`

```
import React from "react"; // react dependencies

const Teams = ({ teams }) => {
  // create Teams component
  return teams.map((team, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <br />{" "}
      <div class="container">
        {team.map((mon) => (
          <React.Fragment key={mon.mon}>
            <br /> <div class="bout">{mon.bout}</div>
            <div class="child">
              <img src={mon.sprite} />
              <p>{mon.mon}</p>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
};

export default Teams;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function1 as a prop to the child element.